# SQL Self-Join Query in a complicated case

Tags: mysql

I am working on a data sum up. about the different prices for different periods.

on the database looks like

```
itemId | Time Start | Price | Time End
  01   | 2012-01-01 | $10   | Null
  01   | 2013-01-01 | $20   | 2013-06-01
  01   | 2014-01-01 | $30   | Null
```

And the tricky Part is The task askw me to output a form like

```
itemId | Time Start | Time End   | price
 01    | 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 | $10
 01    | 2013-01-01 | 2013-06-01 | $20
 01    | 2013-06-01 | 2014-01-01 | $10
 01    | 2014-01-01 | Null       | $30
```

I think it should be done with some statement using SQL Self Join
But so far I don't have any idea to do this.

especially have no idea to how to generate the 'row 3' and 'row 4' which is

`01    | 2013-06-01 | 2014-01-01 | $10`

Problem Descriptions: Each Price related to a specific time slot. And there some cases like:

```
Case 1: if the time slot has start time and end time, just show it.(simple) 

Case 2 : if the end time is Null, it will fill the End time from the next start time.

Case 3: (difficult one), This row's start time comes from the The end time from the others row,it has to match the last time slot's End time.  and the end time for this row should match to the start time of next time slot.
```

Comment: This has the makings of a good question. A couple edits could make it better. 1. Explain in words how the table is transformed to the desired output,  2. Add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, i just added some descriptions for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not highly efficient, but it should do the work:

```
select *
from
(
select items1.itemId,
       items1.timestart,
       coalesce(items1.timeend, (select min(items2.timestart)
                                   from items items2
                                  where items2.itemId = items1.itemId
                                    and items2.timestart > items1.timestart)),
       items1.price
  from items items1
union
select items3.itemId,
       items3.timeend,
       (select min(items4.timestart)
          from items items4
        where items4.itemId = items4.itemId
          and items4.timestart > items3.timeend),
       (select items5.price
          from items items5
         where items5.timestart = (select max(items6.timestart)
                                     from items items6
                                    where items6.itemId=items5.itemId
                                      and items6.timestart < items3.timestart)
       )
  from items items3
 where items3.timeend is not null
) itemss
order by 2 asc
```